# xcrun error in instrument

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

[image]I am trying to launch a react native app on simulator and when I run this command in terminal `npm run debug:ios` I keep getting this error

```
Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I though my problem is that I don't have the xcode command line installed, but I do.

What is this problem?

Comment: What results do you get when you run this in Terminal? `which instruments`

And how about this? `which xcrun`

I think the issue probably has something to do with `xcrun` being in your `PATH`, but somehow, `instruments` is not. For me, they're both in the same directory, `/usr/bin`.

Comment: I just added the errors I am getting

Comment: Thanks, but please read the first comment and execute the statements in Terminal. It will help shed light on where `xcrun` and `instruments` are. If you list the directory where `xcrun` is found, then `instruments` should be in the same directory (it is for me, at least, and I don't really have any reason to believe it should be anywhere else).

Comment: And you could also try deleting and re-installing Xcode, which will reinstall the Command Line Tools (though I don't know for sure if `instruments` constitutes a command line tool). You may also want to make sure you have all updates that your macOS App Store app wants to install.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it for me: http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-fix-xcrun-error-unable-to-find-utility-instruments-not-a-developer-tool-or-in-path/

> You need to launch XCode and agree to the terms first. Then go to `Preferences > Locations` and you'll see a select tag for Command Line Tools. Click this select box and choose the version of XCode you'll be using.
>
> After this you can go back to the command line and run `react-native run-ios`